# XAMPP on Ubuntu Securing Directory Issue

Tags: php, xampp

I am making a directory on a ubuntu server using XAMPP. I am trying to secure the directory with a password and have had no success:
I tried running this command:

```
sudo htpasswd -c/opt/lampp/htdocs/[myreponame]/.htpasswd username
```

then i go through with entering the password. After that i've ran

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp
```

restart to restart and then try loading the page and it does not ask for the password. I've also tried doing similar command:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /opt/lampp/etc/xampp/.htpasswd [username]
```

then enter the password restart services as shown above. When i do it this was it still does the same thing loads the page without asking for a password. I try accessing it by

```
localhost/repo_name
```

any ideas or suggestions. I've spent a good few too many hours on it. I want to secure this properly since security is very important.

Comment: See post here not sure why it came across this way format wise.
https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/5zdlaw/xampp_on_ubuntu_server/?st=j09tn56r&sh=9839487d

Comment: why use insecure software when security is an issue?! The maintainer of xampp advices to not use this software for production evironments.

Comment: I am using XAMPP to test it out prior to putting it into production. I plan on using Nginx for the final version. I guess I can just avoid the security XAMPP and continue testing and then move to Nginx when I want to launch the production.